# Setting up php phantomjs

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs, php-phantomjs

I am trying to setup Phantomjs on my Server and my hosts have installed the binary at "/usr/bin/phantomjs "

reading the documentation from http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/ i have tried the following

```
$client->getEngine()->setPath('\usr\bin\phantomjs');
    $client = Client::getInstance();
```

but i get the error : Call to a member function getEngine() on a non-object in

anyone able to assist with the setup?

Comment: Check the slashes, you are using backslashes in your call to setPath

Comment: Thanks - this sadly didn't solve the issue

Comment: And obviously the two lines need to be swapped...

Comment: @MarcoSandrini Should be the answer :)